# How to implement hashCode cleanly?

Tags: apex, design-patterns

Being able to write your own equals/hashCode for a custom class seems appealing - see [Non-primitive Types in Map Keys and Sets](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Winter13/Map+Keys+Sets). But with no hashCode method exposed in Apex string or decimal or any of the other primitive types, building a correct and efficient hashCode for a custom class that has a few fields of different types looks way harder than it should be.

Suggestions?

Comment: Yes most interesting, wondering why the only sample is using numbers as an example? ;-) Looks like there is a bug in this area at large anyway, http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SV0XAAW

Comment: Good gawd, that bug makes the entire feature unusable if it's really that simple a repro. Even if it wasn't there, Keith is right, not exposing hashCode in the primitives makes it more painful to roll your own. Until that happens, best bet is to create a set of primitive hash utility methods that copy the logic from Java or .NET. Still the point is moot until they fix maps and sets.

Comment: On na14 these pass:

Comment: I saw the bug report but couldn't reproduce. What I see is that these pass on na14 but not on na3 system.assertEquals(1, numberSet.size()) system.assertEquals(1, numberMap.size()) and this fails on both system.assertEquals(t1, t2). A new low has been reached here.

Comment: Salesforce broke your link so hard. Here is a newer [version](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000171329&language=en_US).

Comment: Even that link seems broken now... for reference it was Article #000171329.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Summer'13 Update:**

According to the Summer'13 release notes String now provides a hashCode method! Here is the sample code included in the release notes [here](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf).

```
public class MyCustomClass {
    String x,y;
    public MyCustomClass(String a, String b) {
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    public Integer hashCode() {
        return (31 * x.hashCode()) ^ y.hashCode();
    }
    public Boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MyCustomClass) {
            MyCustomClass p = (MyCustomClass)obj;
            return (x.equals(p.x)) && (y.equals(p.y));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

Converted comment to an answer after a bit of digging around.

**Initial thoughts...**

Yes most interesting, I did wonder why the only sample was using numbers. It also looks like there is a bug in this area at large anyway, http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SV0XAAW.

**Current conclusion...**

I had a look at the Java implementations and a few other general postings on the net. My conclusion is that given the statement governor, at least for strings, it is going to quite expensive to implement a String.hashCode. We really need a native implementation of this to avoid hitting the statement governor very quickly with large maps.

**Some interesting links**

- http://java-bytes.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/hashcode-of-string-in-java.html
- http://www.tgerm.com/2011/07/xcollections-using-udt-with-map-set-in.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()
- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation

Comment: Could an MD5 hash generated using the Crypto class be used as a substitute?

Comment: Have just been trawling the Apex docs and came across that, the trick is going to be turning this into an Integer to return from the hashCode method.

Comment: It shouldnt matter right, if the string (blobs) are 'equal', the resulting hashes should be the same ?

Comment: I'm just not sure how both equals and hashCode could be implemented this way though? (putting aside its a big hammer for a large nut of course) How would the hashCode method be implemented?

Comment: Posted [Expose hashCode on all Apex primitives so hashCode viable for custom classes](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000jwWXAAY) in the IdeaExchange to at least publicise that particular problem a bit more.

Comment: [Summer 14 Release Notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/api/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm) show `equals` and `hashCode` of System.System (Object?)

Comment: Just want to know, how `hashCode` method implementation will help ? or the use of it ? I have understood `equals` method that it will help in object comparison, so set and map will detect duplicate objects. @daniel @andrew

Comment: @Ankuli - If you do `return System.hashCode(this);` you get an infinite loop

Comment: Andrew - your approach leads to Integer overflow with the exponentiation which, although it doesn't throw an exception, the resulting integer has lost significant digits. Why not do `return String.valueOf(this).hashCode();`

Answer (score 2):

I realize Summer '13 is just around the corner, but if you are still looking for a way to create a hashcode out of strings (or any other object) without hitting governor limits, here is a method I pieced together [using the solution found here](http://smgoodyear.com/2012/12/17/generating-hashcodes/)

```
private static final Long prime = 524287L;
public static Integer getHashCode(Object obj) {
    String objHex = null;
    if(obj instanceof Id) {
        objHex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Blob.valueOf((String)obj));
    } else if(obj != null) {
        Blob objJSONBlob = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(obj));
        Blob objHMAC = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA1', objJSONBlob, Blob.valueOf('a key that does not matter'));
        objHex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(objHMAC);
    }
    if(objHex != null) {
        Long hash = 0L;
        for(String sChar : objHex.split('')){
            if(String.isEmpty(sChar)) {
                continue;
            }
            hash = ((hash ^ hexToInteger.get(sChar)) * prime);
        }
        return (Integer)hash;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```