# Trigger to prevent insert record between two dates

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Hi what I am trying to do is write a Trigger for a custom object where users can pass in a from and to date. Now I am trying to make sure that they can't put another record between those 2 dates i.e. from and to dates

for example:

record1: from: 23 dec 2015 to: 24 dec 2015 **fine**

record2: from: 24 dec 2015 to: 25 dec 2015 **Error**

record3: from: 1 dec 2015 to: 23 dec 2015 **Error**

record4: from: 1 dec 2015 to: 11 dec 2015 **fine**

Comment: Going to need a trigger to do this I believe

Comment: Hi Eric thanks for your comment. Can you give code example for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variants on this question have been solved a few times by [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox). The basic idea is to use [complex map keys](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4569/how-to-implement-hashcode-cleanly) and abuse the `equals` method to detect overlap.

You will indeed need `Apex` to validate in this way. First, create an object you can use to detect overlap:

```
public class DateRange
{
    final Date startDate, endDate;
    public DateRange(Date startDate, Date endDate)
    {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public Integer hashCode() { return 1; }
    public Boolean equals(Object instance)
    {
        DateRange that = (DateRange)instance;
        return startDate <= that.endDate && endDate >= that.startDate;
    }

    public static DateRange factory(MyObject__c record)
    {
        return new DateRange(record.From__c, record.To__c);
    }
}
```

Now, your code needs to generate a `Set<DateRange>` and check against it for each record. If you want to validate against ranges already in the database, you need to query for them as well.

```
Set<DateRange> ranges = new Set<DateRange>();
for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
{
    DateRange range = DateRange.factory(record);
    if (ranges.contains(range)) // <= where the DateRange.equals method is called
        record.addError('<message_here>');
    else
        ranges.add(range);
}
```

Comment: `startDate <= that.endDate && endDate >= that.startDate` is sufficient. I've already optimized that logic.

Comment: I thought it was something like that but I couldn't quite get it working. I'll change the logic to match that.

Comment: Yeah, I had to sit down with a pen and paper to arrive at that solution. It makes a lot more sense if you draw it out first.

Comment: I do love me some pen and paper solutions. Some of the most fun!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to use validation rules for this if you want to validate across the entire set of objects.

You could create validation login in apex using a trigger to do this though. If you query all the existing instances of the Object you could build a list of the used dates and validate your new records against that - using sObject.addError() to display the error the same way a validation rule would

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger TestTrigger on <Your object>(before insert,before update) {
List<<Your object>> ListOf= new List<<Your object>>([SELECT Start_Date__c, End_Date__c FROM <Your object> limit 10000 ]);

for(<Your object> OBJLIST:ListOf) {
    for(<Your object> NewObj: Trigger.new) {
        if((NewObj.End_Date__c>= OBJLIST.Start_Date__c && NewObj.End_Date__c<= OBJLIST.End_Date__c) ||
               (NewObj.Start_Date__c >= OBJLIST.Start_Date__c && NewObj.End_Date__c<= OBJLIST.End_Date__c) ||
               (NewObj.Start_Date__c >= OBJLIST.Start_Date__c && NewObj.Start_Date__c <= OBJLIST.End_Date__c) ||
               (NewObj.Start_Date__c < OBJLIST.End_Date__c&& NewObj.End_Date__c> OBJLIST.End_Date__c )
              )
            {
                NewObj.addError('Your Message.');
            }
    }
}}
```