# Validate records by date ranges in SOQL and apex en bulk

Tags: apex, trigger, date

I have a custom object with two dates - start and end. When inserting multiple records, I want to ensure they don't overlap at all. Naive implementation:

```
global with sharing class OverlapFilter_TDTM extends hed.TDTM_Runnable {
    final static String MESSAGE_DUPLICATE_FOUND = 'This is already being used as a match source: {0} ({1}-{2})';

    Map<String, Some_Object__c> getDuplicatesMap(Set<Id> sources, Set<Date> starts, Set<Date> ends, List<SObject> newlist) {
        Some_Object__c[] duplicates = getDuplicates(sources, starts, ends, newlist);
        Map<String, Some_Object__c> ret = new Map<String, Some_Object__c>();
        for (Some_Object__c i : duplicates) {
            ret.put(i.Some_Lookup__c + i.Start_Date__c.format() + i.End_Date__c.format(), i);
        }
        return ret;
    }


    Some_Object__c[] getDuplicates(Set<Id> sources, Set<Date> starts, Set<Date> ends, List<SObject> newlist) {
        return [
                SELECT
                        Id,
                        Some_Lookup__c,
                        Start_Date__c,
                        End_Date__c
                FROM Some_Object__c
                WHERE Some_Lookup__c = :sources
                AND ((
                        Start_Date__c >= :starts AND Start_Date__c <= :ends
                ) OR (
                        End_Date__c >= :starts AND End_Date__c <= :ends
                ) OR (
                        Start_Date__c <= :starts AND End_Date__c >= :ends
                ))
                AND Id NOT IN :newlist
        ];
    }
    global override hed.TDTM_Runnable.DmlWrapper run(
            List<SObject> newlist,
            List<SObject> oldlist,
            hed.TDTM_Runnable.Action triggerAction,
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult) {

        Set<Id> sources = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Date> starts = new Set<Date>();
        Set<Date> ends = new Set<Date>();
        for (Some_Object__c i : (Some_Object__c[]) newlist) {
            sources.add(i.Some_Lookup__c);
            starts.add(i.Start_Date__c);
            ends.add(i.End_Date__c);
        }
        if (!sources.isEmpty()) {
            Map<String, Some_Object__c> duplicates = getDuplicatesMap(sources, starts, ends, newlist);
            if (!duplicates.isEmpty()) {
                for (Some_Object__c i : (Some_Object__c[]) newlist) {
                    // they key does not match range here
                    Some_Object__c dupe = duplicates.get(i.Some_Lookup__c + i.Start_Date__c.format() + i.End_Date__c.format());
                    if (dupe != null) {
                        i.addError();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem with my naive implementation is with Map key not working when dates don't match exactly...

I think the easiest way would be just iterate the array again and use date functions to compare and find duplicate, but that seems computationally expensive...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger to prevent insert record between two dates](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140877/trigger-to-prevent-insert-record-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2):

Finding overlapping dates is one of those things that you *think* should be easy, but is actually hard. I mean, sure, it's easy enough to tell if two date ranges overlap or not (just see if the start or end date of the shorter range falls within the start or end date of the larger range), but that's an O(n^2) operation. It's not going to scale well.

#### SOQL can't really help you here

When you have more than one collection that you're filtering with (as you do with starts, ends, and sources), any filter that you add is likely going to *increase* the number of results returned. Yes, even if you use `AND`.

This is because filters on collections end up becoming a filter on the *cartesian product* of the individual collections.

If you have `(a, b, c) AND (1, 2, 3)`, your filter ends up becoming

```
(a AND 1) OR (a AND 2) OR (a AND 3) OR 
(b AND 1) OR (b AND 2) OR (b AND 3) OR 
(c AND 1) OR (c AND 2) OR (c AND 3)
```

If you find the earliest start date and the latest end date, that (combined with your filter on the lookup field) can help you limit the rows returned at least somewhat. So SOQL isn't completely useless, it's just not able to effectively compare date ranges.

#### Can we avoid an O(n^2) comparison?

I think we can.

This problem reminds me of one I solved some years ago. If we need to assign a range of IP addresses, how can we tell if all of those IP addresses are free (i.e. not assigned)? If even one IP address in our target range is used, the entire range is invalid.

IP address ranges (i.e. blocks, subnets) had some nice properties that made it  easy to represent in a binary tree (each decrease in the prefix length = a doubling of the number of IP addresses, network boundaries aren't arbitrary, network sizes are always a power of 2).

Date ranges are, unfortunately, not as accommodating. Being able to have ranges of arbitrary size (1, 2, 3, 19, etc...) makes it harder to break things down into reasonable sub-trees. We can still use a tree structure to help us here though.

I imagine that we can represent a range of dates as a start date + a duration (i.e. `startDate.daysBetween(endDate)`), and organize our tree by date components (year, month, and day). That is, each time we step down a level in the tree, we go to the next more specific date component. If the current node in the tree represents a year, each of its 12 children will represent an individual month.

Each node in the tree can store its date component, as well as the number of free days it contains.

The basic algorithm would then be:

1. Create a new tree, let's call it the "available" tree, with a 3-year root node (assuming that your date ranges aren't going to be years-long affairs, having the prior year, this year, and the next year should be sufficient), and set it to have 365 (or 366) free days
2. Take your date range, and use it to build a tree (to tell you how many days in the year(s), and month(s) that you need), let's call it the "request" tree
3. Take the 3-year root node of your "request" tree, and compare it against the 3-year node of your "available" tree
4. If your number of requested days is greater than the number of available days, then the requested range overlaps with previously scheduled ranges and you can stop
5. Else, continue the check
6. Repeat this check for the individual year nodes, the month nodes, the "week" nodes (optional, just a grouping of 7 days with no regard to the actual calendar weeks), and the day nodes
7. If you traverse your entire "request" tree, then there is no overlap, and the range can be scheduled
8. You'd then update your "available" tree to reduce the number of free days in each week, month, year, and 3-year node, and mark the individual days as "not available"

There's probably some improvement to be had, and providing an implementation is more than I'm willing to do, but this should give you a start. The main idea is that you should be able to save compute time by using a tree structure to reduce the number of comparisons you have to make.